# how to print options for function python

Tags: python, gdal

I have a python script for gridding using GDAL and part of it is made of the options I want to pass to the function like so

```
option = gdal.GridOptions(format = 'MEM', outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32,  width = x, height = y, \
outputBounds = [self.xyz_dict['minX'], self.xyz_dict['minY'], self.xyz_dict['maxX'], self.xyz_dict['maxY']], \ outputSRS = srs, algorithm=self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm'])
```

I'd like to check what exactly is being passed as the output isnt as expected so I tried `print(option)` but this is giving me `(<osgeo.gdal.GDALGridOptions; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALGridOptions *' at 0x7f0dd57b1c90> >, None, None)`

How do I print it properly?

Comment: not sure. but maybe you can try : print (list(option))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(option)` returns the memory reference of the object.
You can try printing the arguments before calling the function like this-

```
arguments = dict(format = 'MEM', 
outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32,  
width = x, 
height = y,
outputBounds = [self.xyz_dict['minX'], 
                self.xyz_dict['minY'], 
                self.xyz_dict['maxX'], 
                self.xyz_dict['maxY']], 
outputSRS = srs, 
algorithm=self.jobDict['gridAlgorithm']
)
option = gdal.GridOptions(**arguments)
```